# How to avoid duplicate code when writing the body to a interface method?

Tags: java, interface

I have a 'product' superclass and products subclasses and for some of these products a 'temperature' attribute should be set. I have made a 'Freezer' interface with the 'setTemp' and 'getTemp' methods. When I write the body for these methods, in all of the cases it is the exact code for 'setTemp' and 'getTemp'. How can I avoid writing duplicate code in this case?
Thanks, 
Ovidiu.

Comment: does 'product' inherits from 'store" ? This does not sound right - It would give more sense when a 'store" would have several 'products'... so composition and not inheritance. Also your text indicates that product does implement the 'Freezer' interface, which also would be wrong

Comment: A store superclass and a product subclass? Since when is a product a store?

Comment: How about a subclass of Store with a variable 'temperature' , getter /setter for 'temperature', which will be extended by 'products' requiring a temperature attribute ?.

Comment: Wha are you tagging this with three different programming languages? Are you asking about Java, C# or ABAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `Freezer` an [abstract class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) instead of interface (or leave it as interface and create an abstract class `AbstractFreezer`) and implement this particular piece of logic in it:

```
public abstract class AbstractFreezer extends Product implements Freezer {
    private int temp;

    @Override
    public void setTemp(int temp) {
        ...
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: @Codebender that quite depends on context, which is not entirely clear in such small examples (at least for me). The other option to avoid duplicate code is composition, but that seemed inappropriate for this case to me. If you have an idea for a better design (using composition or any other approach), I'd really appreciate if you could post that as your answer as I'm interested about alternative approaches.